# how to get rid of "Untrusted Connection" error

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I have developed a web application and used my certificate for SSL. I don't need the CA certificates, because the client is connecting to the server in an intranet. So the client will get the Untrusted Connection error every time. do you have any idea how we can get rid of this error in each browser? I tried to add my generated certificate to the browser but it didn't work and it didn't recognize my certificate type.

thanks,

-- Mana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For intranet you create a custom CA and import it as trusted into the browsers. You don't use this CA directly in the web application, but you create with this CA a certificate which matches the hostname of the web application and use this for the web server. Because your intranet CA is trusted by the browser it will accept all certificates created by this CA.

Comment: thanks, but I don't know how to import it as trusted into the browsers. could you please help me for this?

Comment: depends on the browser. Google provides you with enough answers to this question

Comment: I tried to add the certificate to the browser. but my browser didn't recognize my certificate, maybe because that wasn't from a valid CA root.

Comment: like I said, you don't add the certificate, but the CA to your browser. You might get more details from http://datacenteroverlords.com/2012/03/01/creating-your-own-ssl-certificate-authority/, which is the first google hit when searching for "create your own ca browser"

Comment: thank you so much. I also found this site useful:  http://www.poweradmin.com/help/sslhints/